# What do these Chrome policies mean?

Tags: google-chrome

Hi: I got a new Macbook from work and it does have some software installed from work. When I started up Chrome, I noticed that there was a cryptic message that it was managed by an organization. I looked at the policies and these two policies were in place:

[AuthNegotiateDelegateWhitelist](https://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#AuthNegotiateDelegateWhitelist) and 
[AuthServerWhiteList](https://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#AuthServerWhitelist)

I deleted these in terminal because I just want as little connections as possible between my computer and my employer. Does anyone know what these policies do? Have I caused some problems for myself?

Comment: [su] is for home users and enthusiasts. If you have a question about your company provided computer you need to talk to your IT department. FYI, it looks like you are using the term “my computer,” very loosely.

Comment: This is not your computer. It belongs to the company you work for. Don't modify it. You don't get a choice in how much connection it has to your company because it isn't your computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have cut off your access to some company server(s) and so to some company
services or proxies, or to logging to company servers without a credentials prompt.
This is fine if you don't need these servers and/or services in your work,
but otherwise you will need to ask the IT people to restore these settings.

`AuthServerWhitelist` specifies which servers are allowed for integrated authentication. By default, however, this only supports *impersonation* not delegation.

So, if you add a server to `AuthServerWhitelist`, you can, for example, log in to a website which can then impersonate your user. However, let's say that website would further want to connect and authenticate to an SQL Server database *on behalf of your user*. That would not work since this is *delegation*.

Adding the server additionally to `AuthNegotiateDelegateWhitelist` should enable that delegation use-case, provided you are using Kerberos (Negotiate) and everything has been set up correctly.

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52001656/165358)